# Remove those self-accept actions in the reputation tab!

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

I just found out that I forgot to accept my own answer to a question of mine asked a long time ago. So I accepted it. Then, I went to check on the reputation I earned today in the reputation tab of my profile.

I saw this:

[image]

Apparently, that self-accept action which neither gave nor took any reputation at all appears in the reputation tab! How ironic! The purpose of the reputation tab is for people to see what events earned them reputation or made them lose reputation, right?

So an event like self-accepting which doesn't give or take any reputation should not be shown in the reputation tab! It should be treated like the other events of this kind, like upvoting, editing, or voting to close others' posts!

Well, yeah I admit this doesn't really do anything bad to the site and the community, but it just feels weird and makes little sense.

Comment: Self-accepts are the exception, not the norm. 99% of the time, acceptance does have an impact on reputation. Special-casing self-accepts just to display them in another tab looks like a lot of trouble for little gain.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  I'm not suggesting that they should be put in another tab. Just remove it from the rep tab.

Comment: From *it should be treated like the other events of this kind, like upvoting, editing, or voting to close others' posts*, I assumed you wanted to display them somewhere else. Even if it is not the case, though, I believe my point stands -- IMHO there is little value in removing that information just because it is a special case that does not yield reputation.

Comment: Instead, remove `ability to accept your own answer` like `you can't vote-up/down your own answer`. Let community decide a better answer by their `voting privilege`.